# How to add check box to series in a chart in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts

I have a chart with multiple series as lines. These are appearing in the legend and i am trying to add some sort of control to the user so that it is possible to enable or disable the series in the graph based on the users preference and hence trying to add check boxes. I cant find any info anywhere. Is it possible?

Comment: What charting API are you using?

Comment: using chart controls in windows forms

Comment: The question is tagged as WPF, but you say you're using windows forms now? Which chart controls, specifically? Or have you written them yourself? I think we need some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding a separate `CheckedListBox()` and by tracking the indexes of both the series and checklistbox items i can show or hide the series.

Answer (score 0):

assumption: you are using MsChart...
have a look at the Position-Property of your Series Objects.
the SeriesPosition-Object has two Properties that could help you:

Excluded and Hidden